# Отображение изменения значений таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можна отследить изменения внесенные в данные таблицы, если данные удалялись, вставлялись, обновлялись. В последствии чего отобразить измененные значения??

Comment: Доп. таблица логов, и триггеры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [CDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb522489.aspx)

Comment: что, это такое?

Comment: пройдите по ссылке и узнаете

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО)))

Comment: примите ответ как правильный

Comment: Предоставлено недостаточное число аргументов для процедуры или функции cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ ... ???
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
    @source_schema = N'dbo',
    @source_name = N'InventoryStudents',
    @role_name = N'cdc_Admin',
    @capture_instance = N'HR_InventoryStudents',
    @supports_net_changes = 1,
    @filegroup_name = N'PRIMARY';
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10)
SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('HR_InventoryStudents')
SET @to_lsn   = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_HR_InventoryStudents
(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'all');

Comment: USE Job1;
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_enable_db;
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
    @source_schema = N'dbo',
    @source_name = N'InventoryStudents',
    @role_name = N'cdc_Admin',
    @capture_instance = N'HR_InventoryStudents',
    @supports_net_changes = 1,
    @filegroup_name = N'PRIMARY';

DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10)
SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('HR_InventoryStudents')
SET @to_lsn   = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_HR_InventoryStudents
(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'all');

Answer (score 0):

Добавить поле timestamp и при каждом обращении с помощью Select Max(timestamp) From ... и при каждом обращении сравнивать с ранее сохраненным значением. Более сложно - создать еще дополнительную таблицу для Delete From ..., а в основной дописать триггер

Comment: Как определить что произошло? Удаление, Вставкиа или Обновление?

Comment: В пером случае - только вставка или обновления. Что из них произошло - по первичному ключу, если Identity. Второй случай, с определением старых значений и поддержкой Delete - не для краткого комментария. Могу сбросить фрагменты кода - multisoft@rambler.ru

Comment: скинь пожалуйста на reactor-rector@mail.ru